# Why does aqeous fluorescein shine when exposed to UV light?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, fluorescence

I know that (aq) fluorescein *"absorbs"* UV light and releases light in the visible spectrum , but how does it do that. It is a really interesting and useful organic chemical and I just wanted to know what goes on in it so that it lights up.

[image: Fluorescein dissolved in water]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is called [fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence). Some substances, such as calcium sulfide, $\ce{CaS}$, absorb light and release it slowly in a process called [phosphorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence), glowing for some time after the source of light is removed.

Comment: Your answer is usefull!